# How i can integrate BigBlueButton into my Django website

Tags: django, bigbluebutton

I'm trying to use an API called **BigBLueButton** in my website, and after a little researches, i figured how to install it in my project using the command `pip install django-bigbluebutton`. I add it to my **INSTALLED-APP** in **setting.py**.
Until this step, everything is OK and i have no errors. But i don't know how use its models and its views and how to show it in my website. Does anyone have an idea of ​​the next steps? Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [docs](https://github.com/Execut3/django-bigbluebutton) , it provides a admin section which is named as Meeting.
So fron there you can manage meetings (create, join, share, etc.)

Comment: So. all i need after the installation and setting up BBB is to import the Meeting class in my view and start working. Great, thanks for your help, i appreciate it :)

Comment: Yes and for more information about use of library check [test.py](https://github.com/Execut3/django-bigbluebutton/blob/master/django_bigbluebutton/tests.py)